# DataGridView ALL Cell in a row should appear in TextBox like 'Edit' mode?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am Using a DataGridView which contains user data (first name, last name, user id, pw). User can edit one row at a time.

When i start editing a record in the grid, all fields should **appear** (TextBox like) editable. Using DataGridViewTextBox columns only. But only current cell ( User Name) appears editable at first and none of the other fields appear to be editable. It is also the first place the edit highlight appears.

But i want all my edit cell should be appear 'TextBox' like edit mode. And also the cursor should land in the First Name column. The user should be required to fill in the table from left to right, providing the first name, last name, User name and pwd, in that order.

The question is ' How to show all cell in a row should appear like TextBox-like 'Edit' mode? [TextBox like means -- White background with rectangle border and should be highlighted if not currently edited]

Comment: not sure , why did you get downvote...

Answer (score 0):

So you're asking for all of the cells to be in EditMode when you're editing a row. As far as I know, a DGV can only have one cell in EditMode. Default behavior is that when a cell is being edited, it ends the EditMode status of the previous cell being edited.

You're best bet would be to look into writing a custom DGV control, inheriting from the .Net control and maybe overriding the editing functionality. I'm not sure if it's possible, but that's something you should look into. You can also look online for already existing custom solutions, maybe for purchase or as freeware.

Hope this helps.